# Twitter share loads image only on second attempt

Tags: twitter

I have these meta tags and https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator is OK for my URL, but when I use https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=MYURL it loads the image and meta info only from the second attempt(I have to share it one more time or refresh the Twitter share page).

```
<meta name="description" content="news!!! " />
<meta property="og:title" content="Community" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://..." />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://.....JPEG-ml5qvczll" />
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://....2eb5.JPEG-ml5qvczll" />
<meta property="og:description" content="news!!! " />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://..../post/696" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="https://....com/" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="- Community" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="news!!! " />
<meta name="twitter:domain" content=".....com" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@news data" />
<meta name="next-head-count" content="20" />
```

Comment: If it is a brand new link / post then it probably needs the Twitter crawler to fetch the information and cache it.

Comment: @AndyPiper but if I refresh this page https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=MYURL it works fine after 1 second. On the first load, there is no image, on the second everything is ok.

Comment: right, so pasting it causes the card crawler to go fetch the info and it takes a short moment to update. I don't know how the crawler would know about your link unless you already pasted it to a Tweet Composer or into the validator.